# How to use OAuth accesstoken to acquire profile images from various providers using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet and Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

I've created a web application that uses the OAuth authentication and universal connectors as explained in this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/12/integrate-openauth-openid-with-your-existing-asp-net-application-using-universal-providers.aspx), and started to fiddle around a little to add support for other providers like Yahoo and LinkedIn. So the authentication part works and users are created in the asp.net Membership provider. Also, all the providers return the accesstoken which I supposedly can use to retrieve more information regarding the user.

I'd really like to acquire the profile image, but it seems every provider has a different way of requesting this information. Twitter even describes a way to [authorise every request](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) by changing the HTTP header information.

Whilst reading this information on the websites of the various providers I was wondering whether this functionality isn't also already included somewhere in `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet` or `Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth` implementation.

How can I use `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet` and/or `Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth` to request the profile image of the loggedin user using the just acquired accesstoken?

**UPDATE in response to Leo's answer**

I use the following code to make a call on LinkedIn's API.

```
string accessToken = extraData["accesstoken"]; // Extra Data received from OAuth containing the accesstoken.
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,date-of-birth,email-address,picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=" + accessToken);
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
   // do something with response here.
}
```

Error message is "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple...you can't use any of these. These are wrappers of OAuth and OAuth only specifies how you can authenticate a user. Now, to request the user's profile photo you will need to use the external provider's own API and you will need most likely a valid access token. So, you will need to use one of these implementations of OAuth to authenticate a user and the recieve an access token, store the access token somewhere (usually a cookie) and then use the access token to make sub-sequent calls to the provider's APIs. Examples and links....

Facebook's Graph API allows you to retrieve users profiles

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/

notice that all examples in the link above will require you to include the access token in a parameter named access_token, for example

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?method=GET&format=json&suppress_http_code=1&access_token={your-access-token}
```

Google...

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token={your-access-token}
```

LinkedIn...

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,date-of-birth,email-address,picture-url)?oauth2_access_token={your-access-token}
```

You can get more specific information from these providers' websites

Let me know if you have any other doubts I might be able to help you since I have implemented stuff like these before.

Cheers, Leo

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for your suggestions. I think this is what I've been struggling with all morning. I have the accesstoken from the OAuth response. Using the LinkedIn URL that you provide I keep getting a 401 Unauthorised response from LinkedIn. I haven't stored the accesstoken in a cookie, is that required? Please also see the update of my question.

Comment: Ok, possible causes are...that the access token has expired or the access token has not been granted the necessary permissions. When you authenticate a user with OAuth you must request the permissions your application will need. These permissions are shown in the LinkedIn login prompt when the user is logging in

Comment: To expand a little on the above...notice that thw link I provided is asking for specific user profile info(id, first-name, email-address, etc), some of them will require your application to request a specific set of permissions. You should be able to find more info on the LinkedIn developers site

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for helping. The LinkedIn consent page (where I log in) is saying that I have to agree on sharing "YOUR PROFILE OVERVIEW Name, photo, headline, and current positions". Also if I change the link you provided to only requesting first-name I still get the same error. Any clue?

Comment: By the way, storing the access token in a cookie is not required. It's just a common sense solution rather than storing it somewhere else such as a database and making a round trip to the database on every request  just to retrieve the access token. However,  if it is stored in a cookie the browser will already included on every request. But in saying that, the built in library you are is probably doing that work for you already

Comment: Just some extra information, the Facebook link you provided seems to respond with some json, unfortunately the profile image is not in it but that seems like I've asked the wrong question and should be fixable. Perhaps my problem is concentrated around LinkedIn.

Comment: Try this with facebook..https://graph.facebook.com/me?method=GET&format=json&suppress_http_code=1&access_token={your-access-token}

Comment: Yes that one works, it's LinkedIn that's giving me headaches! :) Unfortunately I started with LinkedIn as my first attempt so it put me down quite quickly but now that I know I'm not doing it principally wrong (considering Facebook likes what I do), I'm going to try a few others and see what happens there. Perhaps it's *just* LinkedIn that's being difficult.

Comment: I think it is the .NET OAuth implementation your using...I've done it manually and it works. But, I'm using their OAuth 2 APIs since they have dropped support for OAuth 1a and there's no clear documentation about it. I'm suspecting your application is using LInkedIn Oauth 1.0a. Have a look at this link...http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication